# Is there one word for last week, in a similar way that two weeks is a fortnight?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm specifically looking for last week as one word, but all answers might be interesting.

Comment: Difficult to prove a negative, but I am pretty sure there isn't a single word.

Comment: Can you give more context? Specifically why you think "_fortnight_" is relevant? _Fortnight_ isn't a word for "_the **last** two weeks_" just for "_two weeks_", so you'd still have to say "_last fortnight_" as two words.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Surprisingly, it would appear that there is such a word:

> **yesterweek**
> n.    1.  The week last past; last week.
> [- Webster's 1913 Dictionary](http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/Yesterweek)
>
> **yesterweek**
> *noun* 1. last week.
> *adverb* 2. during last week.
> First recorded in 1830-40; yester- + week
> [- Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/yesterweek)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=yesterweek&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyesterweek%3B%2Cc0) suggests that the word has had some currency in the language:

[image: Ngram of "yesterweek"]

Here are a couple of examples of its usage (emphasis, mine):

- I did not have the mother's milk necessary for an ointment for the eyes. so I used garlic and goose far left from Cloctoring Morwenna's boils **yesterweek**.
  [- "Catherine, Called Birdy" By Karen Cushman](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=e88NW3z-OYMC&pg=PA10&dq=%22yesterweek%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-w4be3-_UAhWDEbwKHX0bAnYQ6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=%22yesterweek%22&f=false)
- "TDearly beloved brethren : Bruno and Nolan ; bogholders and stationary lifepartners off orangey Saint Nessau Street were explaining it avicendas all round each other ere **yesterweek** out of Ibn Sen and Ipanzussch.
  [- Finnegans Wake by James Joyce (book III, chapters 1-4)](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=y_oKAQAAMAAJ&q=%22yesterweek%22&dq=%22yesterweek%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv5LKL4O_UAhUIhbwKHZ4gDKUQ6AEINTAD)

Comment: Simple, yet obscure. I like it.

Comment: and there's even a yesteryear, which is surprisingly more popular than yesterweek

Comment: @shabunc The common usage of "yesteryear" is not a literal "exactly one year ago". Instead, it's most frequently used in a (metaphorical?) sense of "days gone by" - particularly with a nostalgic connotation. Someone talking about "yesteryear" is more likely talking about the 1920s or the 1960s, rather than 2016 specifically.